# Remove "ActiveMQ.Advisory.Producer.x" prefix

Tags: java, spring-boot, activemq-classic

Problem:

- Somehow producer is sending event to "ActiveMQ.Advisory.Producer.Queue.Queue" instead of "Queue"

Active-MQ admin console in Topics section Screenshot with producer-queue: (Not sure why it has queue and 0 consumers and number of message enqueued = 38)
[image]

Active-MQ admin console in Queues section Screenshot with consumer-queue: (it shows consumers = 1 but number of message enqueued  = 0)
[image]

Attaching Producer, Consumer and Config code.

Producer

```java
public void sendMessage(WorkflowRun message){
        var queue = "Queue";
        try{
            log.info("Attempting Send message to queue: "+ queue);
            jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(queue, message);
        } catch(Exception e){
            log.error("Recieved Exception during send Message: ", e);
        }
    }
```

Listener

```java
@JmsListener(destination = "Queue")
    public void messageListener(SystemMessage systemMessage) {
        LOGGER.info("Message received! {}", systemMessage);
    }
```

Config

```java
@Value("${spring.active-mq.broker-url}")
    private String brokerUrl;

    @Bean
        public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() throws JMSException {
            ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory  = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory();
            activeMQConnectionFactory.setBrokerURL(brokerUrl);
        activeMQConnectionFactory.setWatchTopicAdvisories(false);
        activeMQConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection(ActiveMQConnectionFactory.DEFAULT_USER,
                ActiveMQConnectionFactory.DEFAULT_PASSWORD);
        return  activeMQConnectionFactory;
    }
```

Comment: I recommend you read the [ActiveMQ documentation on advisory messages](https://activemq.apache.org/advisory-message).

Comment: I have disabled 'activeMQConnectionFactory.setWatchTopicAdvisories(false);' as mentioned in the documentation link above. But it is not working, do you have any other solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your producer starts, the ActiveMQ broker produces an 'Advisory Message' and sends it to that topic. The count indicates how many producers have been created for the queue://Queuee-- in this case 38 producers have been created.

Since the message is not being produced, it appears that in your Spring wiring, you have the connection, session and producer objects being created-- but the messages are not being sent.

Additionally, if you are showing queue://ActiveMQ.Advisory.. showing up you probably have a bug in some other part of the app (or monitoring tool?) that should be configured to consume from topic://ActiveMQ.Advisory.. instead of queue://